# Artifactory build up does not have repo path

Tags: artifactory

I am uploading build info using the Artifactory Rest API, but it doesn’t have the repo path.

I have added properties in artifact:

Build.name and build.number which is successfully linking to my build but it does not show any repo path in build

How can I get the repo path added manually?

Comment: How do you create the build info?

Comment: I copied build info manually from artifactory documentation and updated with all the required values. I copied some of the values from artifcat like sha, build name etc

Comment: Generating the build info manually is a very complicated mission. The build info is generated automatically using JFrog CLI or other CI plugins. Is there a reason for not using the JFrog CLI?